# Failed to create D3D11 swapchain: The application made a call that is invalid

Tags: qt, qml, directx

I'm trying to deploy a QT app on my `windows server 2012 R2`. I've developed app on my windows 10 and it worked fine on the development machine but it doesn't show GUI on my Windows server.

The problem is related to loading `directX` dlls I suppose. The screen shot of the [debugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) on my windows server is attached herewith.

[ListDlls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls) shows that on windows server, that app couldn't find
`C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll` because its not even there!

I've tried to copy the `d3d11.dll` from my development machine to server but then the app complains about missing `api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll` and the list goes if i copy individual dlls.

What could be the possible solution ?

[image]

I've also installed [Desktop Experience](https://blog.rmilne.ca/2015/08/24/install-desktop-experience-windows-server-2012-r2/) on my server machine but the same error message appear as above.

Comment: As the message says, you should enable the debug layer to get more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/